# Get an identity value in a controller for INSERT (Execute Insert command and return inserted Id in Sql)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, controller

Currently, I am using MVC on creating a project. Now I want to insert an Identity ID value into an INSERT statement.

In my controller:

```
string payment = @"INSERT INTO Payment(Payment_Method,Currency_Type,Total_Amount) 
                         VALUES('{0}','{1}',{2})";
        int pay = DBUtl.ExecSQL(payment, "Cash", currency,total);
        if (pay == 1)
        {
            string pid = "SELECT TOP 1 Payment_id FROM Payment ORDER BY Payment_id DESC";
            int paymentid = DBUtl.ExecSQL(pid);
        if (cart.Count() != 0)
        {
            string order = @"INSERT INTO [Order](Order_Name,Order_Description,Order_Quantity,Payment_Id) 
                     VALUES('{0}','{1}',{2},{3})";
```

Now, I want to the payment_id that already been inserted into the `payment` table which is the first statement and retrieve the payment_id and use it into the INSERT statement for the `Order` table

How can I achieve that?

Please Help

Thank you

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `DBUtil` code consists of:

```
public static int ExecSQL(string sql, params object[] list)
{
    List<String> escParams = new List<String>();

    foreach (object o in list)
    {
        if (o == null)
            escParams.Add("");
        else
            escParams.Add(EscQuote(o.ToString()));
    }

    DB_SQL = String.Format(sql, escParams.ToArray());

    int rowsAffected = 0;

    using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(DB_CONNECTION))
    using (SqlCommand dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand())
    {
         try
         {
              dbConn.Open();
              dbCmd.CommandText = DB_SQL;
              rowsAffected = dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch (System.Exception ex)
         {
              DB_Message = ex.Message;
              rowsAffected = -1;
         }
     }

     return rowsAffected;
}
```

And as you know `ExecuteNonQuery` denotes the numbers affecting the row

So, You can do as shown below:

**FOR SQL SERVER 2005 and above**

```
   using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(@"Your connectionString"))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Payment(Payment_Method,Currency_Type,Total_Amount) output INSERTED.Payment_id VALUES(@Payment_Method,@Currency_Type,@Total_Amount)",con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment_Method", "Cash");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency_Type", currency);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Amount", total);
            con.Open();
        
            int payment_id =Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
                con.Close();
        
            return payment_id ;
        }
}
```

also, you can change your query to:

```
"INSERT INTO Payment(Payment_Method,Currency_Type,Total_Amount) VALUES(@Payment_Method,@Currency_Type,@Total_Amount)"; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
```

Comment: Hi Hesam, I tried your method but is still not showing the payment_id

Comment: Be sure it works, because I've already tested it, as you can see on this link  (https://forums.asp.net/t/2132465.aspx?Get+PK+Id+of+newly+inserted+row+using+C+), (ASP.NET forums) it uses `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` for this situation. you can also visit this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 (`learn.microsoft.com`)

Comment: Is insertion done? what value does it return?

Comment: It shows an error at the return payment_id.
The error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to IActionResult  "

Comment: As for now, I tried a SQL statement to get the value but it also not working.
I will post my method down at my answer.

Comment: for solving this error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to IActionResult` you can try this `int payment_id =Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())`

Comment: I also tried and is still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

For now, I tried something like this:

```
public IActionResult SaveDetail(List<Cart_Has_Services> cart,double total,string currency)
    {
        string payment = @"INSERT INTO Payment(Payment_Method,Currency_Type,Total_Amount) 
                         VALUES('{0}','{1}',{2});";
        int pay = DBUtl.ExecSQL(payment, "Cash", currency,total);
        if (pay == 1)
        {
            object pid = DBUtl.GetList("SELECT Payment_id FROM Payment");
            int paymentid = Convert.ToInt32(pid);

                if (cart.Count() != 0)
        {
            string order = @"INSERT INTO [Order](Order_Name,Order_Description,Order_Quantity,Payment_Id) 
                     VALUES('{0}','{1}',{2},{3})";
            foreach (var item in cart)
            {
                    int ord = DBUtl.ExecSQL(order, item.Cart_Service, item.Additional_Notes, item.Quantity,paymentid);
```

As for now, the codes will run by inserting the values into the payment table. After that, I want to get the payment_id for my next insert which is the order table.

The method that I tried to get the payment_id does not work.

Comment: yet another error, is not working for Object

Comment: could you tell me the 'DBUtl' product name and it's assembly or namespace, and that what version of the product you've installed